# Display Swift array of strings on separate lines in auto resized label

Tags: xcode, swift, fmdb

I have a Swift string array populated via a FMDB SQLite result.  The array prints OK to the console window.  Rather than printing to the console, I would now like to have the strings in the array show on separate lines in an auto resizing label (tests_label).

Only slightly less than new to XCode, so thanks for you patience!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var tests_label: UILabel!

    var databasePath = NSString()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

        let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String

        databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("vmd_db.db")

        let myDatabase = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

        if myDatabase.open(){

            var arrayData:[String] = []

            let query_lab_test = "SELECT lab_test FROM lab_test"

            let results_lab_test:FMResultSet? = myDatabase.executeQuery(query_lab_test, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            while results_lab_test?.next() == true {

                if let resultString = results_lab_test?.stringForColumn("lab_test"){

                arrayData.append(resultString)

            }
        }
            var multiLineString = join("\u{0085}", arrayData)
            tests_label.text = multiLineString
            tests_label.numberOfLines = 0
            tests_label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
            tests_label.sizeToFit()
            //println(arrayData)
            myDatabase.close()
    }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a string separated by newline character, like following:

```
let string = array.joinWithSeparator("\u{0085}")
```

Or in Swift 4:

```
let string = array.joined(separator: "\u{0085}")
```

Then just assign it to the label. For `UILabel` you probably should set `numberOfLines` to zero and resize it using `sizeToFit()` or some more sophisticated way.

Comment: @Adam...Thanks, but I'm using XCode 6.4 and I don't think joinWithSeperator is available in that version.  I tried just join but get an error: 'Cannot invoke 'join' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a TextView widget...ideal for scollable lists:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var tests_scroller: UITextView!

    var databasePath = NSString()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

        let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String

        databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("vmd_db.db")

        let myDatabase = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

        if myDatabase.open(){

            var arrayData:[String] = []

            let query_lab_test = "SELECT lab_test FROM lab_test ORDER BY lab_test ASC"

            let results_lab_test:FMResultSet? = myDatabase.executeQuery(query_lab_test, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            while results_lab_test?.next() == true {

                if let resultString = results_lab_test?.stringForColumn("lab_test"){

                arrayData.append(resultString)

            }
        }
            var multiLineString = join("\n", arrayData)
            tests_scroller.text = multiLineString
            myDatabase.close()
    }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```